# Is there a word for a student/person counted in a roll call

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that represents someone who has been accounted for during a roll call or similar process if one exists. It may be considered to be the opposite of an absentee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attendee

Collins English Dictionary defines it as:

> a person who is present at a specified event

If they had to sign a register, then they might be a "registered attendee", as opposed to an unregistered attendee (who is, presumably, a "gatecrasher").